# Github search only org repos

Tags: github, search, github-organizations

I'm searching for org repos, not interested in user repos. I'd like to contribute to an orgs open source project.

Can I search for all org repos that meet certain criteria ? i.e. a certain topic, certain language and with a size smaller than 10MB of source code.

As far as I know, I can do that for a given org. But I'm unable to execute the same query on all existing orgs.

Thanks

Comment: Have you found a way to search only in org. repositories? I think not have support for it.

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/searching-on-github/searching-for-repositories